# Textbox to Combox

Tags: c#

I need help figuring out couple things.

I have form1 with a multiline textbox1 and I'm adding names to it. When I close that form it calls form2.

I can't figure out how I can add all the lines in textbox1 to a combobox in form2. And have the same value in every form I call from form2 (form3, form4, and so on) to have to same combobox and values.

Hope I was able to explain it.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the lines into an array, like this:

```
 string[] lines = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
```

Then, send this array to the form2 (one way is through the constructor), something like this:

```
Form2 f  = new Form2(lines);
```

Then, in the form2, fill the combobox, like this:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(lines);
```

Comment: Hi Renato,Thanks for the quick response. I tried that but I'm getting "form1 doesn't contain a constructor that takes one argument". Also how can I have the same combobox with the same values in other forms? Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to change the form2 to receive that array in the constructor. Look for something like this: Public Form2() {....} and change to Public Form2(string[] lines)